# Minimum Window Substring in Swift exceeds LeetCode runtime benchmark

Tags: swift

This is a popular question on LeetCode:

```
Given two strings s and t of lengths m and n respectively, 
return the minimum window substring of s such that every character in t (including duplicates) 
is included in the window. If there is no such substring, return the empty string "".

The testcases will be generated such that the answer is unique.

A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters within the string.

Example:
Input: s = "ADOBECODEBANC", t = "ABC"
Output: "BANC"
Explanation: The minimum window substring "BANC" includes 'A', 'B', and 'C' from string t.
```

I converted the [java solution provided by LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/solution/) to Swift since this is the language I am practicing in. Here is my code below:

```
func minWindowSlidingWindow(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> String
{
  if s == t
  {
    return s
  }
  
  var uniqueCharacterHashTable: [Character: Int] = [:]
  
  for character in t
  {
    if let countOfChar = uniqueCharacterHashTable[character]
    {
      uniqueCharacterHashTable[character] = countOfChar + 1
      continue
    }
    
    uniqueCharacterHashTable[character] = 1
  }
  
  let uniqueCharactersRequired = uniqueCharacterHashTable.keys.count
  var uniqueCharactersFormed = 0
  
  var currentWindowCharacterHashTable: [Character: Int] = [:]
  
  var minSequenceSize = Int.max
  var minimumSequenceStart = 0
  var minimumSequenceEnd = 0
  var currentStartIndexInt = 0
  var currentEndIndexInt = 0
  
  while currentEndIndexInt < s.count
  {
    let endIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: currentEndIndexInt)
    var currentCharacter = s[endIndex]
    
    if var characterCount = currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter]
    {
      characterCount += 1
      currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter] = characterCount
    }
    else
    {
      currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter] = 1
    }
    
    if let _ = uniqueCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter],
       currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter] == uniqueCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter]
    {
      uniqueCharactersFormed += 1
    }
    
    while currentStartIndexInt <= currentEndIndexInt && uniqueCharactersFormed == uniqueCharactersRequired
    {
      let startIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: currentStartIndexInt)
      currentCharacter = s[startIndex]
      
      if minSequenceSize == Int.max || currentEndIndexInt - currentStartIndexInt + 1 < minSequenceSize
      {
        minSequenceSize = currentEndIndexInt - currentStartIndexInt + 1
        minimumSequenceStart = currentStartIndexInt
        minimumSequenceEnd = currentEndIndexInt
      }
      
      if let characterCountInWindow = currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter]
      {
        currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter] = characterCountInWindow - 1
      }
      
      if let _ = uniqueCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter],
         let currentCharOriginalCount = uniqueCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter],
         let charInWindowCount = currentWindowCharacterHashTable[currentCharacter],
         currentCharOriginalCount > charInWindowCount
      {
        uniqueCharactersFormed -= 1
      }
      
      currentStartIndexInt += 1
    }
    
    currentEndIndexInt += 1
  }
  
  if minSequenceSize == Int.max
  {
    return ""
  }
  
  let startIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: minimumSequenceStart)
  let endIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: minimumSequenceEnd)
  
  return String(s[startIndex ... endIndex])
}
```

This works for the basic test cases but as the string size gets huge [like 100,000 for example](https://pastebin.com/3NsfkL3t) - it gets super slow even though I use the same data structures (I think) as suggested in the Java solution.

Can anyone point me as to where the bottleneck in this code lies and how could I optimize this further.

Comment: If your code works correctly (to the best of your knowledge) and you are looking for a review and improvements, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions is a better place to ask. They have dedicated [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) and [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) tags. – Before you post there I suggest to run more test cases. Unless I am mistaken, the output of (e.g.) `minWindowSlidingWindow("ABCYAYBYCY", "ABC")` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error @MartinR - You are right and now I have run about 8 - 10 test cases which seem to give the desired output, however with the time limit exceeded issue. I will look at codereview stack exchange, thanks for that suggestion as I was not aware of it before.

Comment: Now posted on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/270609/35991. You might consider to delete it here.